# In C what is the difference between a normal array and an array created with malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Let's say I declare an array by doing this:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

By what I understand, you can also create the same array using pointers and malloc:

```
int* array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);  
*(array) = 1;
*(array + 1) = 2;
*(array + 2) = 3;
*(array + 3) = 4;
```

What is the difference between the two ways? Is one necessarily better than the other?

Comment: What if the size is unknown in compile time?

Comment: If the SO duplicate search wasn't so awful I'd find 10 for you.

Comment: This should be explained at the source where you heard about dynamic memory allocation in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one resides in the current function's call stack. The second one resides in the heap.

The first one goes out of scope when the function returns, the second persists until `free()` is called on the address.

More differences, but I defer to the duplicate found by lethal-guitar instead of adding to my answer.

Comment: All right, I actually thought the array's data was stored in the heap. This clears A LOT of things up. Thank you.

Comment: The main difference is otherwise that dynamic memory is... dynamic.

Comment: Yeah I had this misconception about array data's storage. I'm sorry.